# Building CLI app/package in Go

Tags: go

I may be going about this incorrectly (I've read How to Write Go Code), but here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want to write a golang package that also come with a CLI, so that a user can use the package in their own programs but also use the CLI that I've built with it.

So what I have so far is this structure:

```
mypackage/
  -api/
    -account.go // package api
    -node.go    // package api
  -main.go // package main - this is where I want
           // the executable code to be that is put in the `bin` folder.
```

This is a very crude file structure as I'm just starting out the project, but that's what I'm trying to achieve rather than build a package with the usable code in it and then build a separate repo with my CLI in it. But when I attempt to run `main.go`, it says `undefined: Account` (which is a struct in `account.go`).

The contents of my code is unimportant right now, it's very basic as I'm just trying to get the code to work. Here's what I have.

account.go

```
package api

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Account struct {
    email         string
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/username/mypackage/api"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := Account{}

    fmt.Printf("%T", a)
}
```

If this is completely bad practice, I suppose I'll just make 2 repos, one with the CLI and another with my actual package code (again, usable in development by others by importing), but I'd really like it to be an all-in-one repo.

Comment: `Account` is in the `api` package, so you reference it as `api.Account`

Comment: Wow... definitely overthought everything and missed that... That was it. Thanks!

Comment: `api` is a [bad name for a package](https://blog.golang.org/package-names), especially since you explicitly mention other users using your package.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to change. This isn't really fleshed out, just wanted to make sure I had my structure right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "one way", but the common approach is to make your top-level repo your library - i.e. `github.com/you/somelib` and then have a `cmd` directory underneath that contains your CLI (package mains) - there may even be many.

e.g.

```
yourlib/
    api.go
    api_test.go
    handler.go
    handler_test.go
    cmd/
        command-name/
            main.go // Builds a "command-name" binary
        other-command/
            main.go // Builds a "other-command" binary
```

Your CLI apps are just consumers of your library. Users can retrieve it via `go get github.com/you/yourlib/...` which will install the lib and the binaries onto their GOPATH.

The Go [source itself](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/cmd), [Camlistore](https://github.com/camlistore/camlistore) and [BoltDB](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) all use this approach (amongst many other libs).

Comment: So just to clarify, anything in the 'main' package and a 'main' func will be added as an executable in the bin dir?

Comment: Correct - it will get added to `$GOPATH/bin` when you use `go get` to fetch the package.